# Nested jQuery Click Events Different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, click

With this code, Firefox alerts on the button click only. For Chrome, both alerts are displayed.

I would like the behavior the same as in Chrome, where an event is triggered by the `img` when it is clicked (which is ignored by Firefox).

**Note:** my actual code is much longer and more functional. I distilled it to this smaller set of code to isolate the root behavior that is causing me pain elsewhere.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://app.essets.com/system/application/js/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('button').click(function(){
                alert('button clicked');
                });
                $('img').click(function(){
                alert('img clicked');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type='button'>
            <img id="1" class="moduleratingstar" src="http://app.essets.com/images/site/transactions.png">
            Some text
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to reproduce Chrome's behavior across browsers - I'm not even sure what the specs says about this.

You could, however, create a "fake" button, that is, using a others HTML elements styled to look like a button. This way, implementing such behavior would be a no-brainer.

[Take a look at this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/andreortigao/weKVF/1/)

Comment: The spec says that buttons are not allowed to contain interactive content. I think this includes any nodes with click handlers. So most browsers ignore nodes embedded within buttons when looking for click handlers. You'll see the same problem if you try putting an `a` element within a button -- clicking on the link works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox or IE.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll change it to be a styled div. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. For completeness, it doesn't work in Opera either.